# Where else in the Talmud can we find a discussion of natural disasters?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, natural-phenomenon

We read a passage relating to natural disasters in Taanit 5a in which Rabbi
Nachman asks Rav Yitzchak to explain a passage from Kings II 8:1 in which
the people are told that they will suffer through a famine for seven years. He
asks: how can they possibly suffer famine for seven years without supplies of food?
Rabbi Yitzchak replies by quoting from Rabbi Yochanan who explains this verse
in the following fashion: in the first year they will eat from the fields. in the
second year they will eat what they have managed to save; in the third year they
will eat their kosher animals; in the fourth year their *trefah* animals: in the fifth
year they will eat the insects and reptiles: in the sixth year they will eat their
children: and in the seventh year they will eat the flesh from their own arms. Thus
they will survive.

Where else in the Talmud can we find a discussion of natural disasters?

Comment: Are you looking for a list of places in the Talmud that mention natural disasters? Or are you looking for something more significant?

Comment: thanks, seth! something more significant like yez's ruchos

Answer (score 1):

[Berachos 59b](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%3a%D7%91%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%99_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%93%D7%A3_%D7%A0%D7%98) discusses the reason(s) for earthquakes, and the nature of powerful storms.

> מאי זועות א"ר קטינא גוהא רב קטינא הוה קאזיל באורחא כי מטא אפתחא דבי אובא טמיא גנח גוהא אמר מי ידע אובא טמיא האי גוהא מהו רמא ליה קלא קטינא קטינא אמאי לא ידענא בשעה שהקב"ה זוכר את בניו ששרויים בצער בין אומות העולם מוריד שתי דמעות לים הגדול וקולו נשמע מסוף העולם ועד סופו והיינו גוהא א"ר קטינא אובא טמיא כדיב הוא ומיליה כדיבין אי הכי גוהא גוהא מיבעי ליה ולא היא גוהא גוהא עביד והאי דלא אודי ליה כי היכי דלא ליטעי כולי עלמא אבתריה ורב קטינא דידיה אמר סופק כפיו שנאמר (יחזקאל כא, כב) וגם אני אכה כפי אל כפי והניחותי חמתי רבי נתן אומר אנחה מתאנח שנאמר (יחזקאל ה, יג) והניחותי חמתי בם והנחמתי ורבנן אמרי בועט ברקיע שנאמר (ירמיהו כה, ל) הידד כדורכים יענה אל כל יושבי הארץ רב אחא בר יעקב אמר דוחק את רגליו תחת כסא הכבוד שנאמר (ישעיהו סו, א) כה אמר ה' השמים כסאי והארץ הדום רגלי

(summary) what are "zo'os"? Quakes.  They happen when Hashem "recalls" the suffering of His people in exile and sheds two tears into the ocean, and the sound reverberates around the world.  Alternatively (R' Katina), Hashem claps His hands together.  Alternatively (R' Noson), they come from Hashem's "groans".  Alternatively (Rabbanan), from Hashem "kicking" the rakiah.  Alternatively (R' Acha Bar Yaakov), from Hashem "pushing His feet" under the Throne of Glory.

and

> מאי רוחות אמר אביי זעפא ואמר אביי גמירי דזעפא בליליא לא הוי והא קא חזינן דהוי ההוא דאתחולי ביממא ואמר אביי גמירי דזעפא תרתי שעי לא קאי לקיים מה שנאמר (נחום א, ט) לא תקום פעמים צרה והא קא חזינן דקאי דמפסיק ביני ביני

(summary) Ruchos are powerful storms.  Abaye: We know that they only happen at night if they started during the day, and only last for multiple hours if there is a pause in between.